# Combining (rbind) multiple large csv files into one with different column orders

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell, awk

I have multiple large csv files in a folder and I am trying to rbind(concatenate) them into one csv. But, while doing this I want to make sure all column values go in an appropriate column after concatenating. I can't do this in R because of memory limitation. I am pretty much new to shell scripting and I know there might be some way to do that without taking all csv files into memory.

Eg.

```
> csv1
     A  B  C  D  E
     1  2  4  5  6
     4  5  7  8  9
     3  5  6  7  8
     2  3  4  5  8

> csv1
    C  B  E  D  A
    10 22 43 35 66
    14 15 37 48 99
    33 25 56 67 88

> Desired Output
         A  B  C  D  E
         1  2  4  5  6
         4  5  7  8  9
         3  5  6  7  8
         2  3  4  5  8
        66 22 10 35 43
        99 15 14 48 37
        88 25 33 67 56
```

My attempts:

I try to set column order in R for each file while saving and then use below code to concatenate. I want to know a way where I can do everything in linux shell.

```
nawk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' *.csv > result.csv
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not a bash answer, but you can read them in one by one in R, after each read, rearrange/check columns, then write/append to disk

Comment: @Vlo I have tried that but still there is a risk for mismatching. I have mention that in my attempts.

Comment: how large are they ?

Comment: I think `bind_rows()` in the `dplyr` package does this.

Comment: approx ~300-500GB

Comment: @Balter bind_rows() works when I can read large files in R. But, I don't want them in R memory. Kindly check question

Comment: @Rushabh How do you mismatch if you manually define the order after each read? `csv1[c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")]`

Comment: @Vlo I don't mismatch. But, I am sure there might be some way to do everything in shell.

Comment: don't use `bind_rows`, you need to figure out how to do it with command line, build this command with R and send it through `system`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I do it using system command only. But, I am not sure what command I should use to do it in shell. I am pretty new to that.

Comment: You could give the [iterators](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/index.html) package a try.  Forgive me for not offering a solution, but it requires a little more effort than I can spare at the moment.

Comment: @NathanWerth Sure I can look into it. I appreciate for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have large data so couldn't test it on it. Could you please try it once and let me know if this helps you.

***Solution 1st:*** With each time checking and noting the field's numbers and then printing them in all passed Input_file(s):

```
awk '
FNR==NR && FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      b[i]=$i};
  print;
  i--;
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  print;
  next
}
FNR!=NR && FNR==1{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
      c[$j]=j};
  next
}
FNR!=NR && FNR>1{
  for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
      printf("%s%s",$c[b[k]],k==i?RS:FS)}
}
'  csv1 csv2
```

Output will be as follows:

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  2  4  5  6
4  5  7  8  9
3  5  6  7  8
2  3  4  5  8
66 22 10 35 43
99 15 14 48 37
88 25 33 67 56
```

***Solution 2nd:*** checked with OP and OP is ok if I print the data in column's sorted format, so we need NOT to note down the field sequence number each time in all Input_file(s)(Also considering that fields are same in all the passed Input_file(s) too), could be MUCH FASTER I believe compare to previous solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     a[$i]=i};
  if(FNR==1 && FNR==NR){
     print};
  next
}
{
  for(j in a){
     printf("%s ",$a[j])}
  print ""
}
' csv1 csv2
```

Comment: but will it work with multiple csv's. I have approx 10 csv files in a folder.

Comment: @Rushabh, yes it should. Also I prepared one more code, wanted to check with you if irrespective of sequence of csv1, if I give you code which always print fields in sorting order from A B to Z will that work for you? If yes then I believe that could be much faster, let me know on same once.

Comment: I mean order doesn't matter to me. It is ok. You can edit your answer and add that too. I can test both.

Comment: Sure I am testing first one. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165178/discussion-between-rushabh-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: `FNR==1 && FNR==NR` can be shortened to `NR==1`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 your second solution works but it had some less number of columns then original headers. I don't know whats going wrong. I am running first one.

Comment: here also I have less number of rows.

Comment: @Rushabh, as Karfka mentioned check if you have carriage characters by doing `cat -v your_Input_file` if you see`^M` and carriage chars then you could use `tr -d '\r < Input_file > temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` and could try my code again then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 do I have to check for each file individually. I have no clue about shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==1   {split($0,t)} 
       NR==FNR {print; next}  
       FNR==1  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) k[$i]=i; next}
               {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                   printf("%s%s", $(k[t[i]]), (i==NF?ORS:OFS))}' file1 file2 | column -t

A   B   C   D   E
1   2   4   5   6
4   5   7   8   9
3   5   6   7   8
2   3   4   5   8
66  22  10  35  43
99  15  14  48  37
88  25  33  67  56
```

uses the order of the column headers from the first file.  Assumes matching number of columns...

Comment: what  |column -t does?

Comment: similar to pretty print, aligns the fields (since your files have space padding, without formatting it won't look good).  Or you can add `$1=$1` before printing the first file to reformat the lines.  The second file is reformatted because of column swap.

Comment: What is NF in for loop?

Comment: `NF` is the number of fields.

Comment: I don't know what shell script you're running.  Do you have `awk` installed?  Do not include the initial `$` before `awk`  in your code which is the shell prompt.

Comment: I am running exactly what you said. But, I am getting error. When I am running previous answer's second solution it runs without error.

Comment: did you change the file names from file1,2 to your file names?

Comment: No parans, it's not a function.  I just copy/pasted to a bash shell and it works as is.  Sorry, not sure what's wrong with your runs.  Perhaps the script will help to get a sense of the algorithm and programming style...  Perhaps try without `| column -t`

Comment: OK, so your `awk` doesn't have `printf` statement, but just as a function.

Comment: got it. I am waiting for results. I will update once it is done.

Comment: your method is reducing number of rows. Actual final file should have 1222394 rows but your's is giving just 297534

Comment: Not sure it's possible with this code.  How do you measure the number of lines?  `wc -l`?  Double check your line endings especially if you copied files from Windows.